# Make jackson serialize apache commons Pair

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-commons

How can I make jackson, if even possible without making my own complex serializer of `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`, to serialize both my left and right object in a proper way. So for example I have to following code:

```
 public class MyPairTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Address address1 = new Address("Axel Street 1", "London");
        Address address2 = new Address("Axel Street 2", "Copenhagen");

        Map<String, Pair> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("Address", Pair.of(address1, address2));

        Pair p = Pair.of(address1, address2);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        try {
            String serializeMapWithPair = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
            String serializePair = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
            System.out.println(serializeMapWithPair);
            System.out.println(serializePair);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(p));
    }
}
```

And the resulting output is:

```
{
  "Address" : {
    "com.example.api.beans.Address@224edc67" : {
      "street" : "Axel Street 2",
      "city" : "Copenhagen"
    }
  }
}
{
  "com.example.api.beans.Address@224edc67" : {
    "street" : "Axel Street 2",
    "city" : "Copenhagen"
  }
}
{"left":{"street":"Axel Street 1","city":"London"},"right":{"street":"Axel Street 2","city":"Copenhagen"}}
```

So the first two outputs are serializing `Pair` with jackson ObjectMapper where as the last is with Gson, I want to achieve the result as in the Gson example, but with jackson and without the `left` and `right` part. The `Gson` example I got from [this jira improvement suggestion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1204) and I know that they state the following `"Commons-lang has no dependencies, so Jackson or anything similar can not be used."` But was wondering if Jackson them self have made a serializer or the kind for this, cannot find anything like it out there so maybe there is no simple solution to this with jackson? Or should I just drop it and use Gson, and then just manually manipulate and remove the `left` and `right` parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow I think that I will just go with implementing my own generic class with a before and after field and then serialize that, works even how I want it to be in the end, so I end up with something like the following class:

```
public class MyPair<T> {
    private T before;
    private T after;

    private MyPair(T before, T after) {
        this.before = before;
        this.after = after;
    }

    public static <T> MyPair<T> of(final T before, final T after) {
        return new MyPair<>(before, after);
    }

    public T getBefore() {
        return this.before;
    }

    public T getAfter() {
        return this.after;
    }

    public void setBefore(T before) {
        this.before = before;
    }

    public void setAfter(T after) {
        this.after = after;
    }
}
```

and then I can just call `MyPair.of(address1, address2)` and get that serialized as

```
{
  "Address" : {
    "before" : {
      "street" : "Axel Street 1",
      "city" : "London"
    },
    "after" : {
      "street" : "Axel Street 2",
      "city" : "Copenhagen"
    }
  }
}
```

Which is what I was expecting :). Just need to make sure that it is called with the same object type, else throw compile-time error, seems that does not work because right now `of()` can be called with two different types.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom serializer:

```
private static final class PairSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Pair> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Pair value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField("left", value.getLeft());
        gen.writeObjectField("right", value.getRight());
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }

}
```

and register it with your ObjectMapper:

```
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addSerializer(Pair.class, new PairSerializer()));
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question with details:

Jackson treats the `Pair<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>` as an item of a map and generates wrong output.

The only way to bypass is to write your own `Pair` class which NEVER implements the `Map.Entry` interface.

Comment: is that the commons-lang pair? what about the vavr pair?